# RStudio 1.1.383 and rmarkdown 1.7 environment enheritance

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

On Windows 7 64 bits, I have recently updated to RStudio 1.1.383 and rmarkdown 1.7. As I am using `render` to produce a pdf from an Rmd file I have noticed a new behavior.

1. There is leakage between the Global Environment and the knitting environment and it goes both ways:
2. If I define `x = 12` in the .Rmd file, I find `x` in the Global environment after the render is complete.
3. If I use an undefined variable `y` in the .Rmd and I set `y=1000` in the global environment before using `render` then `y` is used in the knitting of the .Rmd
4. If I do knit from RStudio the leakage does not occur and even if `y` is defined in the global environment, knitting the .Rmd will give an error (y not found).

Does anyone know why is that? I believe separating the environment is very important to ensure reproducibility even though it is sometimes painful to get right.

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmarkdown_1.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.2  backports_1.1.1 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.2     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.13   
 [9] stringi_1.1.5   knitr_1.17      stringr_1.2.0   digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Here is the minimal "test render.R" file:

```
library(rmarkdown)
y=1000
render(input = "test render.Rmd")
```

and Here is the minimal "test render.Rmd" file:

````
---
title: "test render"
author: "Courvoisier"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
x = 12
print(y)
```
````

and here is the pdf result:

[image]

Comment: This may be a better question for http://community.rstudio.com/.

Comment: True but they recommend putting it here first

Comment: If it's any help, `rmarkdown` 1.7 was released yesterday I believe and has a bunch of changes relative to 1.6 and 1.5.

Comment: ah thanks. I thought it was in August (release version on github) . I guess it only went on CRAN yesterday.

Comment: @lmo StackOverflow is totally fine, and personally I strongly recommend StackOverflow for Q&A. As the maintainer of the rmarkdown package, I rarely read posts on community.rstudio.com (I just don't have time to) but I read every post on StackOverflow. Let's not suggest users move back and forth between two sites unless the question on SO is obviously inappropriate as a question.

Comment: @Courvoisier Verbal description is often vague (from my guess, you missed some critical information in your description: are you running a **Shiny** R Markdown document?). Please bring [a minimal reproducible example](https://yihui.name/en/2017/09/the-minimal-reprex-paradox/) (and please try your best to make it minimal -- an example containing ~100 add-on packages is unlikely to be minimal).

Comment: @Courvoisier BTW, have you tried the curent development version `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")`?

Comment: @YihuiXie thanks - yes I read your comments about posting here first - thanks. I am not using the dev version only cran. Sorry for not providing a minimal example -  you are right, there was too many things in my example. But the problem can be reproduced with the simplest option - the default RStudio Rmarkdown file. There is leakage between the global and the knitting environment. I will edit my question above to show that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this behavior has been there since Day 1. Here is how to prove it. First install the very first version (0.3.3) of **rmarkdown** [from the CRAN archive](https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/rmarkdown/):

```
devtools::install_version('rmarkdown', '0.3.3')
```

And run your example:

```
library(rmarkdown)
y = 1000
render(input = "test render.Rmd")
```

You see `y` is printed (as I'd expect):

[image: rmarkdown 0.3.3]

This behavior is by design and I don't know why it is surprising to you. In R, global variables are accessible from anywhere (by definition). You defined `y` in the global environment, and you should expect it to be accessible in the R Markdown document, too.

The R Markdown document is compiled in the environment `parent.frame()` of `render()`, and all variables will be created in this environment. In your case, `parent.frame()` is the global environment (i.e. `globalenv()`), and that explains why `x` was created in the global environment.

When you click the Knit button in RStudio, it is different because the document is compiled in a separate new (clean) R session. The variable `y` you defined in the current R session will not be available to the new R session. Similarly, `x` will be created in the new session and not in your current R session. Reproducibility is exactly why we chose to compile R Markdown documents in new R sessions instead of the current R session. If a document works in a new R session, it is more likely to be reproducible. If it works in your current R session (via `rmarkdown::render()`), it might just work by chance.

If you have to evaluate code chunks in a separate environment, you need to use the argument `envir` explicitly, e.g.

```
render(input = "test.Rmd", envir = new.env())
```

This way, `x` will not be created in your global environment, but `y` will be available to the code chunk (again, by definition of global variables).

In all, if you really care about reproducibility (like we do), there is an easy way and a slightly harder way. The easy way is to click the Knit button in RStudio, and the harder way is to render the document in a separate R session by yourself, e.g., via the command line

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd')"
```